# How to find matching expressions while using a ParseTreeWalker

Tags: antlr4

Say I'd like to find instances of the expression while using the Java7 grammar:

```
FoobarClass.getInstanceOfType("Bazz");
```

Using a ParseTreeWalker and listening to `exitExpression()` calls sounded like a good first place to start.  What surprised me was the level of manual traversal of the Java7Parser.ExpressionContext required to find expressions of this type.

What's the appropriate method to find matches to the above expression?  At this point using a Regex in place of ANTLR4 yields simpler code, but this won't scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR 4 does not currently include feature allowing you to write concrete or abstract syntax queries. We hope to add something in the future to help with this type of application.

I've needed to write a few pattern recognition features for ANTLR 4 parse trees. I implemented the predicate itself with relative success by extending `BaseMyParserVisitor<Boolean>` (the parser in this example is called `MyParser`).

Comment: Thanks Sam. Can you elaborate on your solution?